# cloudinary_angular XMLHttpRequest cannot load... ...is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, upload, cloudinary

I would like to use cloudinary_angular in my angular project (generator-angular-fullstack).
I´ve spent two days trying to use it but I have always the same problem and I don't know how to solve it.

Has someone experience with this error?

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/djhqderwy/upload. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message seems quite clear to me. The spec for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is [quite easy to find](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=W3C+Access-Control-Allow-Headers).

Comment: Looks like you are trying to send an Authorization header to Cloudinary. Probably a global Ajax handler trying to add it to all Ajax requests.